# Highcharts Default Colors Are Not Same at Pie and Column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Why Higcharst default columns are different for piechart and column chart? You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/RqvU4/ i.e. John has different colors at column and pie? How can I make it same without defining colors by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same color because `highcharts` adds different colors for each `serie`.
You can see default colors [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#colors).

You can set `color` for each serie manually like the following.

```
{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Total consumption',
    data: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        color: '#4572A7',
        y: 13
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        color: '#AA4643',
        y: 23                    
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: '#89A54E',
        y: 19
    }],
    center: [100, 50],
    size: 100,
    showInLegend: false,
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RqvU4/1/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. However I get data via Ajax without color: etc. fields. I want to set pie charts' color set later and same with columns?(Also at beginning I don't know the number of elements)

Comment: @kamaci Let me see if I got it, you want to add the pie chart with the custom color and then set it's colors ? Or do you want to add the pie dynamically with it's color ?